# A theorem about oscillation in Arnold's mathematical methods of classical mechanics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

There is a theorem in page 100 of [Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387968903), which says that:

> If $\cfrac{dx}{dt} = f(x) = Ax + R_2(x)$, where $A = \cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{x = 0}$,  $R_2(x) = O(x^2)$, and $\cfrac{dy}{dt} = Ay$, $y(0) = x(0)$, then for any $\vphantom{\cfrac12} T>0$ and for any $\xi > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x(0)| < \delta$, then $\vphantom{\cfrac12}|x(t) - y(t)| < \xi \delta$ for all $t$ in the interval $0 < t  < T$.

How can I prove this theorem rigorously?

---

Cross-posted at physics.se [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89426/proof-of-a-theorem-about-oscillation).

Comment: This follows from continuity of solution of initial value problems with respect to parameters. For example, for the equation with parameters $x'=Ax+\lambda R_2(x)$, with parameter $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. When $\lambda=0$ you get the linear one, with $\lambda=1$ the original non-linear one (and somework, depending on what statement of this theorem you have :-) )

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain it further?

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that $R$ is smooth.  Therefore if $|f|,|g| < M \le 1$, then $$ |R(f) - R(g)| \le C_1 M |f-g| .$$

Also define
$$ C_2 = \sup_{0 \le t \le T} \|e^{tA}\| .$$

Define
$$ B(\epsilon)  = \{f(t) \in C([0,T]) : \|f\|_\infty \le \epsilon\} $$
$$ G_{x_0}:B(\epsilon) \to C([0,T]) $$
$$ G_{x_0}f(t) = e^{tA} x_0 + \int_0^t e^{(t-s)A} R(f(s)) \, ds $$
Then
$$ \|G_{x_0}(f-g)\|_\infty \le T C_2 C_1\epsilon \|f-g\|_\infty $$
Hence there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that if $\epsilon<\delta_1$, then $G_{x_0}$ is a contraction mapping.
Also
$$ \|G_{x_0}(f)\|_\infty \le C_2 |x_0| + T C_2 C_1\epsilon^2 $$
Hence there exists a $\delta_2$ such that if $\epsilon, |x_0| < \delta_2$, then the range of $G_{x_0}$ is contained in $B(\epsilon)$.

Therefore if $\epsilon, |x_0| < \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, then $G$ has a fixed point.  That will be the function $x(t)$.

Let $z = x-y$.  Then
$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = Az + R(x) .$$
$$ z(t) = \int_0^t e^{(t-s)A} R(x(s)) \, ds $$
Therefore
$$ \|z\|_\infty \le C_2 C_1 \epsilon^2 .$$
Choose $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\xi/(C_1 C_2)\}$.

Comment: Thanks very much! How can you make sure that $x(t) \in A(\delta)$? If can not, then $x(t)$ is not the fixed point of $T$.

Comment: I didn't explain that argument very well.  But I edited the document to say that a similar argument will tell you this.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain $Tsup_{0≤t≤T}∥e^{tA}∥(∥R(f)−R(g)∥_∞)≤Kδ∥f−g∥_∞$ further more? I can not figure out where δ comes from.

Comment: If it were the case that $R(x) = x^2$, then we would have $R(f) - R(g) = (f+g)(f-g)$.  I was saying that if $R$ is smooth, then we can do something similar, were the $f+g$ is replaced by something from a mean value theorem.

Comment: Ok~ your proof assumes that $||x||_\infty \leq \delta$ at the last step while the theorem only under the condition that $|x(0)| \leq \delta$.

Comment: OK, how about this?

Comment: Thanks! But note that $\epsilon$ depends on $x(0)$ so that we can not choose it arbitrarily.

Comment: I'm doing this late at night, so maybe I still am not thinking clearly.

Comment: Thanks! But I think $\|G_{x_0}(f-g)\|_\infty \leq T C_2 C_1\epsilon \|f-g\|_\infty$ should be $\|G_{x_0}(f-g)\|_\infty \leq T C_2 C_1 M \|f-g\|_\infty$ in the proof.

Comment: But $f,g \in A(\epsilon)$, and hence $M = \epsilon$.

Comment: Change $A(\epsilon)$ to $B(\epsilon)$ because $A$ is a linear operator.  And also because $B(\epsilon)$ is a ball.  Also change $<$ to $\le$ to make sure $B(\epsilon)$ is complete.

Comment: Thanks! But at the last step $\|z\|_\infty \le C_2 C_1 \epsilon^2 $ but not \|z\|_\infty \le C_2 C_1 \delta^2. And $\epsilon$ can be limited by $\delta$?

Comment: $\epsilon$ can be any number less than $\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$.